# Installing Homebrew on OS X Sierra

Tags: xcode, macos, terminal, homebrew

After failing to install by running `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"` I did some research on potential causes but no one seems to have reported my particular problem. Namely, when I run this in command line, literally nothing happens, no errors...my terminal simply hangs.

I have verified that I have XCode (version 8.1.0).  What am I missing?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy, what about your internet connection?

Comment: Yes, I am behind a company proxy.

Comment: Then see [How to install an homebrew package behind a proxy?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/228865/how-to-install-an-homebrew-package-behind-a-proxy)